# Creating a temp table and using aggregate select query

Tags: sql, sql-server, temp-tables

I am trying to create a temp table from a sub select query and am receiving an error message

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 5
>   Incorrect syntax near ';'

Here is my query:

```
select * 
into #temp 
from
    (select dollars,  PostingDate, EntryDescription
     from MillsEntOps.dbo.OE_InvoiceGLSumm 
     where Postingdate between '2018/03/01' and '2018/04/11')
```

The error message is :

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 5
>   Incorrect syntax near ')'.

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Your query is ok. Only you need to add an alias to your subquery. otherwise, sql can't recognize it. Because of that you got this error message.

Answer (score 4):

Alternatively you can write:

```
select dollars,  PostingDate, EntryDescription
into #TEMP
from MillsEntOps.dbo.OE_InvoiceGLSumm 
where Postingdate between '2018/03/01' and '2018/04/11'
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you missed alias name

```
select * into #temp from ( select dollars, PostingDate, EntryDescription from MillsEntOps.dbo.OE_InvoiceGLSumm where Postingdate between '2018/03/01' and '2018/04/11')temp_table /* alias name temp_table */
```